# Create a (maybe nested) list of nminimize solutions in a loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm a total newbie in mathematica, so need some help. I understand that my question is about basics, but i couldn't find the answer in docs, google and here.

Here is what i'm trying to do.

```
For[i = 1, i < 10, i++,
 Quiet[s = 
    NMinimize[{Abs[x1] + Abs[x2] + Abs[x3] + Abs[x4] + Abs[x5], 
      Abs[0.055*(x1 + 11) + 0.065*(x2 - 13) + 0.068*(x3 - 47) + 
          0.071*(x4 - 50) + 0.07*(x5 - 43) + 0.852] <= 0.30 * i && 
       Abs[-8.567*(x1 + 11) - 9.057*(x2 - 13) - 9.154*(x3 - 47) - 
          8.937*(x4 - 50) - 8.608*(x5 - 43) - 1359.469] <= 6 && 
       Abs[55.818*(x1 + 11) + 62.22*(x2 - 13) + 64.286*(x3 - 47) + 
          64.945*(x4 - 50) + 63.306*(x5 - 43) + 4747.69] <= 
        1650}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, 
     Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]]

  AppendTo[sols_nested_list, s]???
 ]
```

Here AppendTo is wrond, but i need something like {{f,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5},{f,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}...}

How can i do this?

Thanks in andvance.

Comment: Try `Table[Quiet@NMinimize[...], {10}]`

Comment: Table[Quiet[
  NMinimize[{Abs[x1] + Abs[i x2]}, {x1, x2}, 
   Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]] , {i, 1, 3}]

Comment: Please also see: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121)